# webapp2 how to access PUT data

Tags: json, python-2.7, httprequest, put, webapp2

I am using webapp2 to make a small api.

So for example if I have:

```
import webapp2

class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def put(self):
        self.response.write("this was a test")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/test', Test)
])
```

And I do a request through curl:

```
curl --request PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"content": "test"}' http://localhost:8080/test
```

How would I go about accessing the data `'{"content": "test"}'` that was passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All request data would be somewhere in `self.request`, so in this case take a look at `self.request.body` to find the request's contents and check out the documentation's [Common Request attributes](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html#common-request-attributes) section to see the rest of the options.

You may also want to consider looking at the entire `self` object in a debugger to find out about more interesting properties it has.